# Suport Vector Machine training :Is sklearn SGDClassifier.partial_fit able to train an SVM incrementally?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, svm

I am trying to train an SVM model through sklearn to apply as binary classifier to get audio's Ideal Binary Mask(IBM), applied after a neural network that I am developing for my graduation thesis, however, as shown in
[!this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbOog.jpg), the accuracy never converges. The mean accuracy is always about 50% it doesn't matter how many audios are used, which is random considering we've got only two choices.

```
#SVM instance
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier   
SVM = SGDClassifier(loss='hinge',penalty='l2',warm_start = True,shuffle=True) 

#Start training
CLEAN_DATA_PATH = r"D:\clean_trainset_56spk_wav/"
NOISY_DATA_PATH = r"D:\noisy_trainset_56spk_wav/"

audio_files = os.listdir(CLEAN_DATA_PATH)
shuffle(audio_files)
count = 0    

for filename in audio_files:
    
    if count == 1000:
        break
    
    start = time.time()
    count += 1
    Clean, Sr = sf.read(CLEAN_DATA_PATH + filename,dtype='float32')
    Noisy, Sr = sf.read(NOISY_DATA_PATH + filename,dtype='float32')
    
    print("Áudio " + filename )
    
    Features, ibm = Extract_Features(Clean, Sr,Noisy)    
    y = ibm.reshape(-1,1)
    y = np.ravel(y)    
    Features = sc.fit_transform(Features) # Scale    
    SVM.partial_fit(Features,y,classes=np.unique(y))    
    end = time.time()
    
    print("Files training duration: "+str(round(end-start,2))+ " seconds")
    print("Done: "+str(round((contador/len(audio_files))*100,2))+"%")
```

As far as I know, SGDClassifier.partial_fit changes the weights in small batches, what would allow us to use different files as batches (since each audio contains thousands of samples for classifications. Is it right?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one of your problems is that at every iteration, the samples are on a different scale, because you fit `sc` to every new batch.

```
for filename in audio_files:
    ...
    Features = sc.fit_transform(Features)
```

`sc` should be defined outside of the loop, and used as such:

```
Features = sc.transform(Features)
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot for this. I already could improve the accuracy to about 70% only using a different method to get the IBM, but I didn't realize that on the sc